# How can i get my chrome extension to keep the form that is inside to stay filled as it was when the popup gets closed?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

So, if the user compiles 2 fields and then focus out i want those 2 to be still filled when the user re opens the extension.

Comment: There's a duplicate [Save last session of chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29631815).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how not to lose data when closing and opening chrome extension popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335806/how-not-to-lose-data-when-closing-and-opening-chrome-extension-popup)